Why do LC filters with bigger inductors stabilize faster?

While trying out couple of values for an LC filter with a cutoff frequency of 10kHz I noticed that the configuration with the bigger inductor stabilized much faster than the one with the smaller inductor. It seems a bit counterintuitive to me, shouldn't they have similar graphs? What's going on?
Note that I omitted the ESR for both components, but I doubt that using values for real components will change much.

Did you derive the transfer function for both cases?

The impedance of a capacitor is given as
$$Z_{C} = \frac{1}{j\omega C}$$
The impedance of the capacitor and resistor in parallel is given by
$$Z_{R||C} = Z_R || Z_C = \frac{RZ_C}{R+Z_C}$$
$$Z_{R||C} = \frac{R\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}} = \frac{R}{1+j\omega RC}=\frac{R(1-j\omega RC)}{1+(\omega RC)^2}$$
The impedance of an inductor is given by
$$Z_L = j\omega L$$
The impedance of the inductor in series with the capacitor and resistor is given by
$$Z_{L+R||C} = Z_L + Z_{R||C} = j\omega L + \frac{R(1-j\omega RC)}{1+(\omega RC)^2}$$
$$Z_{L+R||C} = j\omega L\frac{1+(\omega RC)^2}{1+(\omega RC)^2} + \frac{R(1-j\omega RC)}{1+(\omega RC)^2}$$
$$Z_{L+R||C} = \frac{j\omega\left( L(1 + (\omega RC)^2)-R^2C\right) + R}{1+(\omega RC)^2}$$
The circuit has a resonance when the imaginary/reactive part of the impedance is 0. The damped resonant frequency \$\omega_D\$ is found from the equation
$$L(1 + (\omega_D RC)^2)-R^2C=0$$
$$L(1 + (\omega_D RC)^2)=R^2C$$
$$L(\omega_D RC)^2 = R^2C - L$$
$$\omega_D^2 = \frac{R^2C - L}{LR^2C^2}$$
$$\omega_D^2 = \frac{1}{LC} - \frac{1}{R^2C^2}$$
The circuit has a damping ratio \$\zeta\$ found by the equation
$$\zeta^2 = \frac{LC}{R^2C^2} = \frac{L}{R^2C}$$
$$\zeta = \frac{1}{R}\sqrt\frac{L}{C}$$
Thus, if you increase L, or decrease C, while keeping R constant, you increase the damping ratio. A greater damping ratio will cause any ringing to dissipate faster.

Here is a CircuitLab simulation of the L+R||C network.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

@beardeadclown should also run an AC analysis on the circuits which shows the peaking at the corner frequency which further agrees with the above analysis about the damping factor.
